# Docker compose does not work if node_modules are not installed on local machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My goal is to create docker dev environment for a full-stack app: React, NodeJS and MongoDb (with hot reloading). My current dev environment works, but I noticed that "docker compose up" will only work, if the node_modules are installed on my local machine - it otherwise returns an error that nodemon is not installed, or react-scripts not found. It seems like docker is looking for the node files in my local machine, but it should be installing them in the container during the compose, right?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    container_name: server_backend
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
  client:
    build: ./client
    container_name: client_frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Dockerfile (backend server)

```
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 7000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Dockerfile (frontend)

```
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

app architecture

```
- MyApp
-- client
-- server
```

Comment: that depends on your `package.json` if those dependencies are included as `devDependencies` it might as well be, that `npm install` doesn't install them. But by `COPY . .` you are copying all of your local files into the image anyways. So those dependencies which where not installed in the image are now copied from the host. But if they don't exist on the host either, they can't be copied, thus are missing when running hte container.

Comment: They are actually not included as ```devDependencies```.

Comment: I'd say we need more information about your folder structure and volume mounting, but my guess is that you are mounting a top level folder instead of just mounting the srouces. So the node_modules are also mounted and the node_module of the image is then just ignored.

Comment: @pdem What other information can I provide specifically?

Comment: In your app architecture, what are the levels below (probably src or app) As I said, the problem is that your volume, which isn't declared in the DockerFile btw redefine all the content of your project, including node_modules. And as other said, instead of copying ., you could copy exactly the needed files and folder, and for further analysis, you could connect to your container with a bash and list the content of the folders to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that you are copying the whole directory with the `node_modules` when you execute the `COPY . .` command,  try and either specifiy the directory to copy or add a `.dockerignore`.

Found this in the documentation, https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/build-images/#create-a-dockerignore-file